# C# Attribute could not inherited in parameter of method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, attributes, mono

I have an example that I want to use reflection to retrieve Attribute from parameter of method.and output to console.

For example:

```
// Define a custom parameter attribute that takes a single message argument.
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class ArgumentUsageAttribute : Attribute
{
    // This is the attribute constructor.
    public ArgumentUsageAttribute(string UsageMsg) => Message = UsageMsg;

    // This is the Message property for the attribute.
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass 
{
    // Assign an ArgumentUsage attribute to the strArray parameter.
    // Assign a ParamArray attribute to strList using the params keyword.
    public virtual void TestMethod(
        [ArgumentUsage("Must pass an array here.")] string[] strArray, 
        params String[] strList) { }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // Assign an ArgumentUsage attribute to the strList parameter.
    // Assign a ParamArray attribute to strList using the params keyword.
    public override void TestMethod(string[] strArray, 
        [ArgumentUsage("Can pass a parameter list or array here.")] params string[] strList)
    { }
}

public void Test()
{
    Type t = typeof(DerivedClass);
    MethodInfo info = t.GetMethod("TestMethod");
    ParameterInfo[] pInfoArray = info.GetParameters();

    foreach (var p in pInfoArray) 
    {
        if (Attribute.IsDefined (p, typeof(ArgumentUsageAttribute))) 
        {
            ArgumentUsageAttribute usageAttr = (ArgumentUsageAttribute)
                Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(p, typeof(ArgumentUsageAttribute));

            if (usageAttr != null)
                Debug.Log ($"Usage:{usageAttr.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Explain:

`TestMethod` is virtual in `BaseClass` and I add an attribute `[ArgumentUsage("Must pass an array here.")]` before `String[] strArray`.

I overrided `TestMethod` in `DerivedClass`, and the parameter of `String[] strArray` should inherit `ArgumentUsage` attribute from `BaseClass`.

It works in Visual Studio IDE. Output was:

> Usage:Must pass an array here.
>   Usage:Can pass a parameter list or array here.

But it does not work in Unity3D. Output in Unity was:

> Usage:Can pass a parameter list or array here.

(compiler thought that the parameter of `String[] strArray` does not add ArgumentUsage attribute. Actually It should inherit from BaseClass).

So what's the matter with it?

I think it probably the framework version issue?
(Unity3D based on Mono)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You override `TestMethod` but not overload. These are different things. Override is when you change the behavior of a virtual or abstract method. Overload is when you add more methods that have the same name but different arguements, such as `Foo(int x)` and `Foo(int x, string s)`. You can look more into overload vs override if you need.

Comment: Also, the backing field of properties should be basically the same name. Like `Message { get => _message; set => _message = value; }` You also can use auto-properties `Message { get; set; }` instead, when the property is very simple. You can also add accessibility like `Message { get; protected set; }` so now the setter is protected.

Comment: thank you but my question is attribute inherited issue.

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to fix it, which is why I upvoted it.